# Get value of asp.net CheckBox via jquery(true/false)

Tags: jquery, asp.net

**got the answer syntax error**

i want to get value of asp.net check box via jquery , if its selected return true otherwise false. i'm doing this: -

```
  var ApprovalRequired = $('<%= chkRequired.ClientID %>').is(':checked');
  // also
   var ApprovalRequired = $('<%= chkRequired.ClientID %>').val();
```

and the checkbox return in html as

```
  <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chkRequired" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$chkRequired" checked="checked">
```

in either way its returning 'false'. Any idea to get true when checked and false on unchecked

Comment: also `$('#<%= chkRequired.ClientID %>').prop('checked');`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You forgot the `#` in your selector:

```
$('#<%= chkRequired.ClientID %>').is(':checked');
```

That should work